# javascript ajax update table from xml data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I have already set a way to get ajax request from xml and put into table and works flawlessly but the only thing I can't seem to able to do and need is I want it to update the table every 10 seconds and put the new data in the table as long as it continues.

I have tried setinterval but it is putting the data again and again into the table with continuing loop, while I want it just to check a new data in xml and if found put it in the table.

so my html is

```
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Lap</th>
            <th>Split 1</th>
            <th>Split 2</th>
            <th>Split 3</th>
            <th>Time</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the xml data:

```
<data>
    <user>
        <lap>1</lap>
        <split1>30</split1>
        <split2>30</split2>
        <split3>30</split3>
        <time>90</time>
    </user>
</data>
```

and last js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/eovj2kf9ojww5ap/data.xml',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: parse
    });
});

function parse(xml) {
    $(xml).find('user').each(function() {
        var lap = $(this).find('lap').text();
        var split1 = $(this).find('split1').text();
        var split2 = $(this).find('split2').text();
        var split3 = $(this).find('split3').text();
        var time = $(this).find('time').text();
        $('#table').append('<tr><td>' + lap + '</td><td>' + split1 + '</td><td>' +      split2 + '</td><td>' + split3 + '</td><td>' + time + '</td></tr>');
    }); 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/81xq3edx/

Comment: which part of the data is new? do you have a unique identifier for each row that can used to insert or update rows when they are added or changed?

Comment: the new data will always be <user>...</user> as seen in here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/eovj2kf9ojww5ap/data.xml

Comment: `$.ajax GET` tends to cache requests. To avoid it add `cache:false` or change to `POST` or add `.../data.xml?new='+Math.random()` to `url`.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev I have just tested and it is the same repeating over and over

Comment: does your `data.xml` change?

Comment: the data.xml on dropbox was just to give an example so currently using localhost server.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data.xml always contains the dataset you need. I would just empty the table and repopulate it on **setInterval**.

```
function parse(xml){
 $('#table tbody').empty()
$(xml).find(....
}
```

Comment: just test this and it doesn't work and doesn't show the table rows.

Comment: just got to a problem with this.. it adds a lot of unnecessary empty <tr></tr> to the html

Comment: Oh, my bad. Actually just remove the body instead try https://jsfiddle.net/mgyt17z2/4/